# Appium Framework: Can't run test :'remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession' What is that?

Tags: java, automation, appium, appium-android

I am trying to create an appium test framework with testNG.

I decided I wanted to do a very simple test just to check that everything was working ok before deep diving in into adding tables and page objects.

I ran my testNG test and got

```
remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
```

I have no idea what that is or how to fix it.

So my question is VERY simple:

1. What does this message mean?
2. How do I fix it?
3. Is there something wrong with pom.xml file?
4. Is this something wrong with my Appium code?

Here is my pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependencies>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here is my appium test code

```
package android;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;


public class TestDragnDrop {
    static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void DesiredCapabilities() throws MalformedURLException{



        DesiredCapabilities caps =new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "JacquelineNexus5");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.android.apis");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "ApiDemos");

        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),caps);

    }

    @Test 
    //Scenario:  Perform Drag n drop function

    //Given I am on the Home screen 
    //When I  tap Views   
    //Then I will see the View menu 
    //When I am in the 'view menu' I will select 'drag n drop'
    //Then I will see 3 dots in the drag n drop page
    //When  I select a dot and drag it
    //Then I will drop it on the dot below

    public void DragAndDrop(){

        driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Views").click();


        TouchAction t = new TouchAction (driver);
        t.tap(driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Drag and Drop")).perform();

        t.longPress(driver.findElementById("io.appium.android.apis:id/drag_dot_1")).
        moveTo(driver.findElementById("io.appium.android.apis:id/drag_dot_3")).release().perform();
    }



}
```

The Eclipse console

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.11.0
Aug 15, 2018 3:55:05 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
FAILED: DragAndDrop
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.TestDragnDrop.DragAndDrop(TestDragnDrop.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Appium Logs

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.8.1
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"ApiDemos","appPackage":"com.example.android.apis","deviceName":"JacquelineNexus5","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"8.0"},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"ApiDemos","appPackage":"com.example.android.apis","deviceName":"JacquelineNexus5","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"8.0"},"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"android"}]}}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"appActivity":"ApiDemos","appPackage":"com.example.android.apis","deviceName":"JacquelineNexus5","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"8.0"},null,{"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"ApiDemos","appPackage":"com.example.android.apis","deviceName":"JacquelineNexus5","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"8.0"},"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"android"}]}]
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1534415639087 (11:33:59 GMT+0100 (BST))
[Appium] Could not parse W3C capabilities: 'deviceName' can't be blank. Falling back to JSONWP protocol.
[Appium] The following capabilities were provided in the JSONWP desired capabilities that are missing in W3C capabilities: ["appActivity","appPackage","deviceName","platformName","platformVersion"]. Falling back to JSONWP protocol.
[Appium] Consider setting 'automationName' capability to 'uiautomator2' on Android >= 6, since UIAutomator framework is not maintained anymore by the OS vendor.
[Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver (v2.7.0) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   appActivity: ApiDemos
[Appium]   appPackage: com.example.android.apis
[Appium]   deviceName: JacquelineNexus5
[Appium]   platformName: Android
[Appium]   platformVersion: 8.0
[BaseDriver] Creating session with MJSONWP desired capabilities: {"appActivity":"ApiDemos","...
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: acc411f6-ac7c-4fad-9e36-8ab77bc8861b
[AndroidDriver] Getting Java version
[AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_71
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[AndroidDriver] Looking for a device with Android '8.0'
[ADB] Setting device id to emulator-5554
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 8.0.0
[AndroidDriver] Using device: emulator-5554
[ADB] Setting device id to emulator-5554
[AndroidDriver] App file was not listed, instead we're going to run com.example.android.apis directly on the device
[AndroidDriver] Checking whether package is present on the device
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages com.example.android.apis'
[AndroidDriver] Starting Android session
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device'
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell echo ping'
[AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages io.appium.settings'
[ADB] App is installed
[ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[ADB] The installed 'io.appium.settings' package does not require upgrade ('2.3.0' >= '2.3.0')
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell ps'
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 26
[ADB] Device API level: 26
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n io.appium.settings/.Settings -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000'
[ADB] Device API level: 26
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell appops set io.appium.settings android\:mock_location allow'
[AndroidDriver] setDeviceLanguageCountry requires language or country.
[AndroidDriver] Got language: 'undefined' and country: 'undefined'
[Logcat] Starting logcat capture
[AndroidDriver] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.unlock
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages io.appium.unlock'
[ADB] App is installed
[ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.unlock'
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.unlock'
[ADB] The installed 'io.appium.unlock' package does not require upgrade ('2.0.0' >= '2.0.0')
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 8.0.0
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell wm size'
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.product.model'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.model': Android SDK built for x86
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.manufacturer': Google
[AndroidDriver] No app sent in, not parsing package/activity
[AndroidDriver] No app capability. Assuming it is already on the device
[ADB] Getting install status for com.example.android.apis
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages com.example.android.apis'
[ADB] App is installed
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.example.android.apis'
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm clear com.example.android.apis'
[AndroidDriver] Performed fast reset on the installed 'com.example.android.apis' application (stop and clear)
[AndroidBootstrap] Watching for bootstrap disconnect
[ADB] Forwarding system: 4724 to device: 4724
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward tcp\:4724 tcp\:4724'
[UiAutomator] Starting UiAutomator
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'starting'
[UiAutomator] Parsing uiautomator jar
[UiAutomator] Found jar name: 'AppiumBootstrap.jar'
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 push /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-bootstrap/bootstrap/bin/AppiumBootstrap.jar /data/local/tmp/'
[ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
[ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell ps'
[ADB] No uiautomator process found to kill, continuing...
[UiAutomator] Starting UIAutomator
[ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","uiautomator","runtest","AppiumBootstrap.jar","-c","io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap","-e","pkg","com.example.android.apis","-e","disableAndroidWatchers",false,"-e","acceptSslCerts",false]
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'online'
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Loading json...
[AndroidBootstrap] Android bootstrap socket is now connected
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys window'
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] json loading complete.
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Client connected
[AndroidDriver] Screen already unlocked, doing nothing
[ADB] Device API level: 26
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n com.example.android.apis/ApiDemos -S'
[ADB] We tried to start an activity that doesn't exist, retrying with '.ApiDemos' activity name
[ADB] Device API level: 26
[ADB] Running '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n com.example.android.apis/.ApiDemos -S'
[Appium] New AndroidDriver session created successfully, session acc411f6-ac7c-4fad-9e36-8ab77bc8861b added to master session list
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1534415653615 (11:34:13 GMT+0100 (BST))
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appActivity":"ApiDemos","appPackage":"com.example.android.apis","deviceName":"JacquelineNexus5","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"8.0"},"appActivity":"ApiDemos","appPackage":"com.example.android.apis","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"8.0.0","deviceUDID":"emulator-5554","deviceScreenSize":"1080x1920","deviceModel":"Android SDK built for x86","deviceManufacturer":"Google"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 14548 ms - 702
[HTTP]
```

Comment: can you post your appium log too?  Also change your **appActivity** to **com.example.android.apis.ApiDemos**. I don't see any problem with your pom.xml code.

Comment: @Suban Unique excuse my ignorance but won't  using 'com.example.android.apis.ApiDemos'  in both appPackage and appActivity have  be really confusing?

Comment: Use this capability as well `caps.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");` Also kindly check your "AppActivity", I doubt it!

Comment: @Sandeep and @Suban Unique.  So I've made some changes  based on your suggestion  Just ran the test again and I got this  `An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds`  How do I fix this?

Comment: I want to add ran the test OUTSIDE of a testNG framework and it worked perfectly.  So there is no reason why it wouldn't work in testNG

Answer (score 0):

here

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

as per the java-client documentation this version supports `selenium 3.6.0`. So either change your `selenium-java` version to the same or upgrade you java-client to newer version. Please update if you still face this issue.

Comment: Ok, I updated appium server-client to 6.1.0 and It got message   ' Description Resource Path Location Type
The method tap(TapOptions) in the type TouchAction is not applicable for the arguments (AndroidElement)  that problem message appeared twice.

Comment: Its clearly visible that on your code you are using 'AndroidElement' type as param to tap method. It should be of type TapOptions or PointOption. Please read the docs for appium java-client carefully. https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html @fypnlp

Answer (score 0):

I  was able to get to the root cause of this problem with all your help, a few headaches and a lot of research!

Basically I ***originally*** structured my desired capabilities like:

```
public class TestDragnDrop {
    static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

@BeforeTest
public void DesiredCapabilities() throws MalformedURLException{



    DesiredCapabilities caps =new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "JacquelineNexus5");
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.android.apis");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", "ApiDemos");

    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),caps);

}
```

What **I SHOULD have done and the correct way** was to structured my desired capabilities for a Maven/TestNG automation framework test as:

```
public class DragnDropTest {
static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> initDriver() throws MalformedURLException{



        DesiredCapabilities caps =new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "JacquelineNexus5");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
        caps.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.android.apis");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "ApiDemos");

        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }




    @Test 
    //Scenario:  Perform Drag n drop function
```

1. You can create a Test scenario as normal.
2. You can find elements and run tests as normal.

I hope this help anyone else in the future.